# Non-canonical examples of divergent sequences that are square summable?

Tags: sequences-and-series, examples-counterexamples, lp-spaces

The canonical example of a divergent sequence that is square summable,  $\sum_{n = 1}^\infty a_n$ is finite, is the harmonic sequence: $\sum_{n = 1}^\infty 1/n$.

Are there examples of sequences that also satisfy this property outside of the harmonic sequence that also satisfies these properties (divergent + square convergent)?

Comment: The harmonic series example is pehaps the go-to example, the standard example, or the common example, but canonical has a specific meaning in math

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, of course. See stuff like $\{b_n\}_{n\ge 10}$ where, to name a few examples \begin{align}b_n&=\frac1{\sqrt n\log n}\\ b_n&=\frac1{\sqrt{n\log n}\log\log n}\\ b_n&=\frac1{\sqrt{n\log n}(\log\log n)^{2/3}}\\ b_n&=\frac1{\sqrt{n\log n\log\log n}\log\log\log n}\end{align}

Comment: Did you forget about the requirement that it be square summable?  Or did you mean $b_n/n$?

Comment: @RobertIsrael No, I forgot that the trick was with $n\log n$. Thank you.

Comment: Thank you. What is the intuition with these examples?